# rsync files from last 7 days with white-space in filename

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I wrote a bash-script to rsync files from the last few days to a destination.
But it cannot handle files with whitespaces

`` rsync -rav --no-o --no-g  `find /tmp/src -type f -mtime -3` /tmp/dest ``

it runs until a file with whitespace comes and exit with:

```
rsync: -: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1554) [client=3.1.2dev]
```

Comment: Take a look at `--files-from=` option.

Comment: BTW, the general mistake here is covered in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Yes, you see people use `find` or `ls` this way all the time, but those people are wrong. There are numerous alternate, better ways to pass lists of filenames between programs, covered in [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (whereas `ls` [shouldn't be used programatically at all](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score 3):

As [@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) said: use the `--files-from=` option.

First make `find` output a  `null` delimited list of files with the `-printf '%P\0'` option. It will print the relative file path followed by a `null`, to help dealing with special or control characters in names.

Pipe that to `rsync`, with the `--from0` option telling the files list or filters uses `null` delimited entries, and `--files-from=-` telling to read the files list from the standard input (here the pipe-in from `find`).

```sh
find /tmp/src -type f -mtime -3 -printf '%P\0' |
  rsync -rav --no-o --no-g --from0 --files-from=- --relative -- /tmp/src /tmp/dest
```

Comment: @user3184895 I just fixed the `rsync`

Comment: now the problem is: it finds the files, but it gives the full path to the rsync command.
Rsync gets `/tmp/src/file.txt` and will copy the full path to `/tmp/dest`. So the execution works, but the synced file will end in `/tmp/dest/tmp/src/file.txt`

Comment: @user3184895 Fixed the relative path issue